# JDK 8 de 32 y 64 bits

Tags: java

Buenas a todos. Tengo una pregunta no precisamente sobre programacion. Acabo de cambiar mi sistema operativo windows 7 de 32 bits a  windows 7 de 64 bits. 
Utilizo netbeans para programar en java, obviamente tuve que guardar todos mis proyectos e instalar el netbeans de 64 bits y el jdk de 64 bits. Todo parecía ir normal, importe los proyectos y todo. Sin embargo al compilar un proyecto en el que estaba trabajando desde el sistema operativo anterior me di cuenta que no me estaba colocando unos jLabels con el tipo de letra que yo le indicaba. asi que utilicé el siguiente codigo para ver que fuentes trae el jdk 8 de 64 bits:

```
package nuevaarquitectura;

import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
public class Nuevaarquitectura {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println( fonts[i] );
        }
    }

}
```

asi que me di cuenta que en verdad no trae las mismas fuentes que tenia el jdk de 32 bits. 
Mi pregunta es si es esto normal??? existe alguna forma para agregarle las demas fuentes que tenia el jdk de 32 bits?
Lo que en verdad me preocupa es saber si habrá algo mas que no trae el jdk de 64 bits? deberían ser igual y traer lo mismo ambas versiones no???

Answer (score 2):

No te puedo decir si es normal que las versiónes de 32bits y 64bits vienen con fonts distintos, pero si puedes agregar _TrueType_Fonts_ a tu *runtime*.

Tienes que dejar los `.TTF` en la ruta `./jre/lib/fonts` de tu instalación de Java.

Es posible que tienes que agregar las rutas a los fonts a `fontconfig.properties.src`

Comment: no se que ha sucedido, pero esta mañana compilé el programa de nuevo y como por arte de magia aparecieron otra vez las fuentes que tenia en la version de 32 bits; no modifiqué mi codigo ni ninguna configuracion ni actualizacion..... que raro está esto.

Comment: Pasaste por una actualización de Windows por mientras?

Comment: no que yo recuerde.